# How do I add an additional comment to a map using tmap in R?

Tags: r, tmap

I want to add an additional comment to a map in tmap in R that is not the title (I want it to be an additional comments in the lower left corner that specifies the source of the data, example). Is there a function to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider including `tm_credits()` in your `tmap` call...

```
library(tmap)

data(metro) # the Metro dataset from tmap

tm_shape(metro) + tm_bubbles(size = 1) +
   tm_credits("This makes no sense at all...",
             position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"))
```

[image]